# react-router with redux createHistory error 'location' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I try to setup react and react-router with redux,react-redux having the following store initialisation

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware,compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {reduxReactRouter} from 'redux-router';
import { createHistory } from 'history';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import routes from './routes';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger()


export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    let createStoreWithMiddleware;

    const logger = createLogger();

    const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, logger);

    createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(
        middleware,
        reduxReactRouter({routes, createHistory})
    );

    const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(createStore)(rootReducer, initialState);

    if (module.hot) {
        module.hot
            .accept('./reducers', () => {
                const nextRootReducer = require('./reducers/index');
                store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
            });
    }

    return store;

}
```

My app is created with create-react-app, on boot I get in console the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
```

How to debug? How to identify the source of the problem?

Comment: Possible you have an incompatible versions of react-router and history. Do not use history v4 with react-router v3.

Comment: yes I downgraded to react-router to v2 and it works! but seems like this project did not get any upgrade lately.

Comment: I think, downgrade history to v3 is better way. Or upgrade react-router to v4, but its trouble way - there is not enough information yet

Comment: thanks a lot for the tips! I will try